# Evaluating $\sqrt{\left(\cos\theta\right)^2}$ at $\theta=\pi$. Two approaches give different answers ($+1$ and $-1$)

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the value of $\sqrt{\left(\cos\theta\right)^2}$ at $\theta=\pi$

There can be two ways in which people will do this:

- First way: Put the value of theta directly, so $\sqrt{\left(\cos\pi\right)^2}$, answer will be $1$
- Second way: Simplify the expression first and then put the value of $\theta$, so in this case one will get $-1$.

> Why do these two ways give different answers?

Comment: They are not. When we write $\sqrt{x}$ we always mean the positive square root. So we can't write $\sqrt{x^2}=x$, this is not true in general. It should be $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Comment: Answer will be 1, you must have done mistake in second way

Comment: @zenix, its simple to see why the answer is $-1$ in the second way, $\sqrt{\left(\cos\theta\right)^2}=\cos\theta$, now put the value of theta as $\pi$, you will get $-1$

Comment: It will be $|cos\theta|$

Answer (score 2):

The existence of two correct answers is incorrect, because $\sqrt{(\cos\theta)^2}$ is the *principal root* of $\cos\theta,$ so it must be positive. In other words, it is equivalent to the *absolute value* of $\cos\theta.$ It is important not to confuse the solution to an equation like $\cos^2\theta = 1\Rightarrow \cos\theta=\pm 1$ with the principal square root as $\cos\theta$ does not have to be positive in the latter equation.